# Error when using MPI_SEND and MPI_RECV on Windows

Tags: windows, mpi, openmpi

I am following a source code on my documents, but I encounter an error when I try to use `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()` from Open MPI library.
I have googled and read some threads in this site but I can not find the solution to resolve my error.
This is my error:

```
mca_oob_tcp_msg_recv: readv faled : Unknown error (108)
```

Here is details image:

[image: Error message]

And this is the code that I'm following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int rank, size, mesg, tag = 123;
MPI_Status status;

MPI_Init(&argv, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
if (size < 2) {
    printf("Need at least 2 processes!\n");
} else if (rank == 0) {
    mesg = 11;
    MPI_Send(&mesg,1,MPI_INT,1,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(&mesg,1,MPI_INT,1,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    printf("Rank 0 received %d from rank 1\n",mesg);
} else if (rank == 1) {
    MPI_Recv(&mesg,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    printf("Rank 1 received %d from rank 0/n",mesg);
    mesg = 42;
    MPI_Send(&mesg,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
 }
```

I commented all of `MPI_Send()`, and `MPI_Recv()`, and my program worked. In other hand, I commented either `MPI_Send()` or `MPI_Recv()`, and I still got that error. So I think the problem are `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()` functions.

P.S.: I'm using Open MPI v1.6 on Windows 8.1 OS.

Comment: Try disabling UAC (User Account Control) and see if it solves the problem. Open MPI is no longer supported on Windows and you might want to try some other MPI implementation, e.g. MPICH or MS-MPI.

Comment: Hi Hristo, I've disabled UAC by change EnabledLUA in registry. Then i re-run my program, and i still get this error,.

Answer (score 1):

You pass in the wrong arguments to `MPI_Init` (two times argv, instead of argc and argv once each).
The sends and receives actually look fine, I think. But there is also one typo in one of your prints with a `/n` instead of `\n`.

Here is what works for me (on MacOSX, though):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int rank, size, mesg, tag = 123;
MPI_Status status;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
if (size < 2) {
    printf("Need at least 2 processes!\n");
} else if (rank == 0) {
    mesg = 11;
    MPI_Send(&mesg,1,MPI_INT,1,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(&mesg,1,MPI_INT,1,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    printf("Rank 0 received %d from rank 1\n",mesg);
} else if (rank == 1) {
    MPI_Recv(&mesg,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    printf("Rank 1 received %d from rank 0\n",mesg);
    mesg = 42;
    MPI_Send(&mesg,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
 }
```

If this does not work, I'd guess your OS does not let the processes communicate with each other via the method chosen by OpenMPI.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I have updated my code as you say, but it still show this error .

Comment: Well, then I think, the only thing I can say is, that this seems to be legit MPI, which works on other systems at least.

Comment: Hi haraldkl, as you say, maybe the problem is OS, i try this code with Linux OS and it works perfectly. Seem OpenMPI is not compatible with Windows 8.1. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Set `MPI_STATUS_IGNORED` instead of `&status` in MPI_Recv in both places.

Comment: Hi, i have updated like this :  `MPI_Recv(MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,1,MPI_INT,1,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);` But it does not work and i still get this error

Comment: Add `MPI_STATUS_IGNORED` instead of `&status`, not `&mesg`  (like this `MPI_Recv(&mesg,1,MPI_INT,1,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);`)
 and there is an error in `printf("Rank 1 received %d from rank 0/n",mesg);`. It should be corrected like `printf("Rank 1 received %d from rank 0\n",mesg);`

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I have updated `MPI_Recv(&mesg,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);` , and about the printf, in my origin code is `\n` i do not know why when i post it here, it becomes `/n`. I have tested with parameter as you say, but i still get this error.